# how to remove or replace unique characters from string in php

Tags: php

my project uses codeigniter 3 and mysql database. there are data in the table that have weird characters in it like `Â` and I need to either remove it or replace it with the closest alphanumeric character. for example, `Â` can be replaced with `A` when I display it on the html page.

I tried using [forceUTF8](https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8/tree/master/src/ForceUTF8) by copying the code in `/libraries/Encoding.php` and I tried using it in the controllers like this but it results in a 404 page:

**/libraries/Encoding.php**

```
/*disclaimers and copyright notes*/
class Encoding 
{

  const ICONV_TRANSLIT = "TRANSLIT";
  const ICONV_IGNORE = "IGNORE";
  const WITHOUT_ICONV = "";

  protected static $win1252ToUtf8 = array(
        128 => "\xe2\x82\xac",

        130 => "\xe2\x80\x9a",
  ...
```

**/controllers/Test.php**

```
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

use \ForceUTF8\Encoding;

class Test extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function test1()
    {
        $str = "some rÂndom string";
        $str = Encoding::toUTF8($data['body']);
        echo '<pre>'.$str.'</pre>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how are you get these character in the first place? If it is from user input, perhaps the best way to do is to validate user input.

It also depend on what the information is. For example, if it is just username, comment, messages, etc. you could leave it as it is.

However, if it was some data crucial or important, then simply removing these character may not cut it, for example, if a data is written in Japanese, your function would make it into an empty string, which may cause harm to your application

A solution may be `Transliterate` (こんにちは -> konichiwa)

With that said, you can still use REGEX to strip off all character that doesnt match with `preg_replace()` , like `$text = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $text);`

Comment: I think it's because I did something to the table that changed the formatting (we did erase and re-insert and imported the table from other database several times). the input were made by our admin team and I am sure the original content didn't have those characters a few years ago. the data are readable content such as testimonies so I think it's better to remove those weird characters.

Comment: If errors happened during importing, you may want to manually review the error. Using a SQL query with regex, something like `WHERE column_name LIKE %some regex%` if data was actually important in case the format error wasnt predictable

Comment: the importing process have always been successful (no error message on my Navicat) so I suspect it's because we did some importing between tables with different formatting (like utf8 to latin or something). the biggest problem is that I'm not sure exactly what caused the characters to change into gibberish and when it happened.